# ArcGIS Pro: Aggregate Polygon using Aggregate Field not honoured

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, aggregation

**The aim**

For cartographic purposes, certain features have to be generalized depending on the used scale.  One step in this workflow is the aggregate polygons based on a category.

**The problem**

Using Aggregate Polygons in ArcGIS Pro (see: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/cartography/aggregate-polygons.htm), it seems the defined Aggregate Field is not honored. As such, polygons of a different category merge if boundaries touch or overlap.

- In the original dataset some polygons (of a different category already touch boundaries)

**Possible solution/checks**

Code Used:

```
arcpy.cartography.AggregatePolygons(
"Source", "OutputGDB", "5 Meters", 
"0 SquareMeters", "0 SquareMeters", "NON_ORTHOGONAL", None, r"OutputTable", "CategoryField"
)
```

- The Field used for the categories is of type short and numbered e.g. 1,2,3 etc. The documentation does not define a required data type.
- I tried dissolving the dataset or the other way around multipart to a single part.

**Question**

As far as I know, I am doing everything according to the manual, but I cannot produce the desired result.

**Figures**

See below, a figure of a part of the data set to be aggregated. Different colours represent different categories.

[image: A part of the data set to be aggregated. Different colours represent different categories that are not the be aggregated]

Here the boundaries touch, which might cause problems.

[image: Possible problem area]